# Кроссбраузерно определять конец страницы

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, кроссбраузерность, mobile-web

Есть такого рода код:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        alert('Привет');
});
```

Прекрасно работает на десктопе. Но почему-то не работает в мобильной версии.
Из мобилок у меня только iPhone 5C, так что девайсов на тест не велико, но и в режиме имитатции мобилок в Хроме, код тоже не хочет выполняться.
Есть неколхозный и без костылей вариант кросбраузерно отслеживать конец страницы по скроллу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант с использованием кросс-браузерной функции определения высоты документа от [James Padolsey](https://j11y.io/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/):

```js
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == getDocHeight()) {
      alert("Конец страницы");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```